# Itext7 After adding an image to a PDF, there is a problem with the image display

Tags: java, itext7

## Code 1:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream addImage(
            InputStream is,
            byte[] signBytes,
            float imageAbsoluteX, float imageAbsoluteY,
            float imageWidthX, float imageHeightY
                           ) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        writerProperties.setFullCompressionMode(false);
        try(
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(os, writerProperties);
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(is), pdfWriter);
                Document document = new Document(pdf);
        ){
            int pageNum = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
            Image image = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(signBytes))
                    .scaleAbsolute(imageWidthX, imageHeightY)
                    .setFixedPosition(pageNum, imageAbsoluteX, imageAbsoluteY);

            document.add(image);
        }
        return os;
    }
```

## Code 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\aaa.pdf");
                InputStream imgIs = new FileInputStream("D:\\1737267788134879232.jpg");
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("D:\\bbb.pdf");
        ) {
            byte[] imgBytes = new byte[imgIs.available()];
            imgIs.read(imgBytes);

            try(ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = addImage(is, imgBytes, 500, 500, 128, 60);){
                byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(os);
            }
        }
    }
```

## After adding a picture, the PDF displays an incomplete picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeHY7.png)

## what is the reason for this?

what is the reason for this?

Comment: Please share both images file you add and the final PDF.

Comment: Sorry, PDFs are sensitive files and can't be shared

Comment: *"Sorry, PDFs are sensitive files and can't be shared"* - well, without them I can only say that the code looks ok. Thus, either the PDF viewer program is broken or the image is (or the image is encoded in some exotic format variant).